# Reset object focus point

Tags: objects

I merged 2 objects that were quite far away from each other by accident.

I removed one of the objects verts (X), but unfortunately the focus (pressing F to center object in camera) is still off since the old focus point seems to still be there.

I want to focus on the object that I did not delete, can I reset the focus point?

[image]

Comment: Could it be that you've missed a vertex?

Comment: Thats what I thought too but no they are all gone. Really makes no sense.

Comment: Have you accidentally switched from the *Industry Compatible* keymap to the *Blender* keymap?

Comment: @RobertGützkow where can I check that? (focusing for all other objects work fine)

Comment: I see, well then that won't be the case. (You could've checked it in *Edit > Preferences* in the *Keymap* tab)

Comment: Darn, its driving me crazy. Guess Ill have to re-do the model...

Comment: To check for stray vertices. Check 'Bounds' in the object's Viewport Display panel..

Comment: @RobinBetts Doing that def shows how off my bounds are, but there is no stray vertice? I try to select all but nothing.

Comment: Did you hide some verts? alt-H or look in object mode.

Comment: @batFINGER No =/ Maybe its cus I did dissolve instead of delete?